# How do you compare two values of the same generic type in java?

Tags: java, generics, nodes

I have this assignment so I'm not looking for an answer but I just want to understand basically how can we compare two variables of the same generic type in Java using the equals method. I've searched stackoverflow for some answers but only could find using the compareTo method where your class extends Comparable I think.

```
package Maillon;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListeAssociativeChainee<K, E> implements IListeAssociative <C, E> {

    private Node<K> keys;
    private Node<Node<E>> elements;
    private int nbrKeys;

    public ListeAssociativeChainee () {
        keys = new Node<>(null);
        elements = new Node<>(null);
        nbrKeys = 0;
    }
}
```

What it currently looks like:
[image: Visual representation of what my work should do]

What I am trying to do:
[image: And here's what I'm trying to do]

My problem hits when I try to delete an element by looking for it through the associative list with the key and element given in the parametres such as:

```
public boolean supprimer(K key, E element) {
    /*****/
}
```

However, I also have another overloaded method that goes like this:

```
public boolean supprimer(K key, int index) {
    /*****/
}
```

This one says that it deletes an element at the index specified using the key and an index point given in parametres.

Now say that I create an associative list as follow:

```
IListAssociative<String, Integer> testList = new ListAssociativeChainee();
```

where IListAssocivative is an **interface** implemented in ListAssociativeChainee.

now if my list contains values of type **int** as follow:

```
key1 -> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
key2 -> [5, 6, 8]
key3 -> [0, 7, 23]
```

and I want to use the delete method

```
testList.supprimer(K key, E element);
```

and I say:

```
testList.supprimer("key3", 23);
```

instead it's going to call

```
testList.supprimer(K key, int index);
```

and that's because I'm using an **int** and not an **Integer** from what I understand.

now say that I do this:

```
testList.supprimer("key3", new Integer(23));
```

it will  call

```
testList.supprimer(K key, E element);
```

but will look for values of type **Integer** that contains 23.

however, my method `elementExists()` will always return false in that case.

Any tips on how I could do it?

EDIT:

here's my `elementExists()`

```
private boolean elementExiste(Node<Node<E>> listeElements, E element) 
{
        Node<Node<E>> m = listeElements;
        Node<E> tmp = m.info();
        boolean existe = false;
        while(tmp != null && tmp.info() != element) {
            tmp = tmp.next();
        }
        if(tmp != null && tmp.info() == element) {
            existe = true;
        }
        return existe;
    }
```

I know that my problem here is that I'm using `==` to compare and **int** and an **Integer** and this is wrong but I'm not sure how to implement the `equals()` method to compare

Comment: Normally you require `E element` to implement `equals()` such that it return `true` when the elements are in fact equal.  Note that `Integer` already does this.

Comment: `if my list contains values of type int`. I don't follow this. You cannot have a `List<int>`.

Comment: Yes, also as Paul points out you don't have the choice to use `int` with Java generics.  You get autoboxing and `Integer` whether you like it or not.  So all of your Element are `Integer`, just you can unbox them to an `int`.

Comment: Your problem is not because of generics. Your list does not contain values of type int; they are type Integer but because of autoboxing it might appear otherwise at times.  Your idea to use testList.supprimer("key3", new Integer(23)); is completely correct. Thus, your elementExists(..) function is probably broken. You'll need to provide us with more code.

Comment: Yeah you're right I actually have not thought about the fact that each int are actually unboxed Integers thanks for that clarification. But I still don't understand how could I implement an equal method to fix this. I added the `elementExists()` code here you go.

Comment: @PaulBoddington You're right actually what I'm adding are value of type Integers and not ints I just realized that.

Comment: (1) Something for style checkers: when using generics avoid overloading; better make an suprimerParIndice. (2) The interface Comparable can nicely be used for generic key types.

Comment: @JoopEggen (1) I can't because it's an assignment -.- I have to follow the IListeAssociative interface that my teacher gave to us... (2) and I can't implement the Comparable interface as far as I know so I have to find another way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your code provides ambiguous methods like your two delete, the best solution is always to rename the method themselves. Instead of `supprimer(Key, int)`, rename it to `supprimerParIdx(Key, int)`.

You could also check the `instance of` your Object to make sure it's not an `Integer` :

```
if (element instanceof Integer) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Integers are forbidden by my law!");
}
```

or instead of an Exception, unbox and call the other method

```
this(key, element.intValue());
```

This is, of course, dirty in everyway.

On a side note :

`new Integer(23)` : Never do this, use `Integer.valueOf(23)` instead, same goes for most Boxed primitives.

Comment: I like this answer. I tried `Integer.valueOf(23)` and it works a lot better now. I'm going to read why it works later on but I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact that it doesn't instantiate an object of type Integer, But in the case of the `instanceof` this is a good idea I actually thought of it but I thought also that there might be a simpler way using the equals method. Otherwise I'm going with you idea

Comment: Glad that this solution works for you, don't forget to vote up and accept :)

Comment: Still havn't reached 15 rep to vote though ahahaha. Thanks